# First time implementing redux in react by own. Getting Uncaught typeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm implementing redux to fetch data using free API. Could anybody please explain why I'm getting this error and what can be the solution for this.

action.js

```
export const tesla = () =>{
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type:'tesla',
            payload:
            "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=tesla&from=2022-07-17&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=b1e1719ca0724ff9bd9dab0645884e9a"
        })
    }
}

export const business = ()=>{
    return (dispatch)=>{
        dispatch({
            type:'business',
            payload:
            "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=b1e1719ca0724ff9bd9dab0645884e9c"
        })
    }
}
```

ApiReducer.js:

```
import React,{useState} from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const ApiReducer = (state=0,action) =>{
    const type=action.type;
    const [eror,setEror] = useState({});
    const data = axios.get(action.payload).
    then(data=>console.log(data)).catch(
        error=>{
            console.log(error);
            setEror(error);
        }
    );
    if(eror.length!==0) return eror;
    return data;
}

export default ApiReducer;
```

CombineReducer.js:

```
import { combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import ApiReducer from "./ApiReducer";

const CombineReducer = combineReducers({
    value:ApiReducer
});

export default CombineReducer;
```

Store.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from "../reducers/CombineReducer";

const Store = configureStore({
    reducer:reducers,
    preLoadedState:{},
    middleware:[thunk]
});

export default Store;
```

exportAction.js

```
export * as actions from './actions/action';
```

Rexercise.js

```
import React,{useState} from "react";
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux/es/exports";
import { actions } from "./redux";


const Rexercise = ()=>{
    const [data,setData] = useState({});
    data = useSelector(state=>state.value);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
    const Tesla = ()=>{
        setData(dispatch(actions.tesla()));
    }
    const Business = ()=>{
        setData(dispatch(actions.business()));
    }

    return(
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" onClick={()=>Tesla()}>Tesla</button>
                <button class=" mx-2 btn btn-success" onClick={()=>Business()}>Business</button>

                <div className="article text-primary">
                    {data}
                </div>
            </div>
            
    )
}

export default Rexercise;
```

I provided the store in index.html for this App.
The error I'm getting:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
at useState (react.development.js:1622:1)

```
at ApiReducer (ApiReducer.js:6:1)
at redux.js:468:1
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at assertReducerShape (redux.js:466:1)
at combineReducers (redux.js:531:1)
at ./src/components/redux/reducers/CombineReducer.js (CombineReducer.js:4:1)
at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ApiReducer` is not a reducer. You cannot call asynchronous methods in there and you can also not use `useState` in there. On top of that, you are writing a style of Redux here that is >3 years outdated and over 4 times the code modern Redux would be.

Please follow the [official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) - whatever resource you are following right now is giving you outdated and probably outright wrong instructions.